# How long will my .NET 2.0 application continue to work?

Tags: .net, winapi

Each version of Microsoft's .NET frameworks have [a limited support lifetime](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?sort=pn&alpha=.net%20framework), e.g.:

- support for .NET Framework 1.1 ended 09/09/2005
- support for .NET Framework 2.0 ended 12/01/2010
- support for .NET Framework 3.0 ended 12/07/2011

I own [an application from 2004](http://www.ptc.com/products/mathcad/mathcad14-whats-new.htm) that was written with .NET Framework 1.1. If you try to install the .NET Framework version 1.1 on a modern Windows 7 64-bit machine you will get an error - it just won't work. A program written in 2006 is no longer usable; you might as well throw it away.

Does this mean that a program that I write in **.NET 3.5** today will, at some point in the future, just be unusable?

> Microsoft went to great lengths with the Windows API to maintain backwards compatibility. A program written 18 years ago (for Win32 or [Win32s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32s)) will still run on Windows of today. (I know - I own one. It originally ran on Windows 3.1 and still runs on Windows 7 64-bit.)

A *native* program that I write today will still work 18 years from now (likely). But it seems that a .NET program I write today has no assurance that it will continue to function.

Is there any compatibility commitments from Microsoft regarding .NET framework 2.0 or later? I know **.NET Framework 1/1.1** was an ugly stepchild; that .NET framework 2.0 broke compatibility with 1.1; but every framework since 2.0 has been compatible with 2.0.

Is there a note somewhere that if I write a managed application with .NET 2.0 or newer, that it should continue to run on Windows 8, Windows 9, Windows 10, etc.?

---

### The Case of the .NET Framework 1.1 error

Spying on the program using Process Explorer, I found the .NET object it's trying, and failing, to create:

[image]

It's class:

- clsid: `{60EBA0BC-D6AF-41C2-9584-D48D3DA39999}`
- progid: `Engine.Factory`

So I created a little test application to see if ***I*** could create the same COM object:

```
const Guid CLSID_EngineFactory = '{60EBA0BC-D6AF-41C2-9584-D48D3DA39999}';

IUnknown unk = CoCreateIntance(CLSID_EngineFactory, null, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER | CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IUnknown);
```

Which fails for me too. I find the registration details in the registry:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID
   {60EBA0BC-D6AF-41C2-9584-D48D3DA39999}
      InprocServer32
            (Default)       mscoree.dll
            Assembly        mcengr, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
            Class           Engine.Factory
            RuntimeVersion  v1.1.4322
            ThreadingModel  Both
```

If the program *should* run with .NET framework 4 installed, then I suppose I can blame the application's installer.

That very well may be the answer to my question:

- while .NET Framework 1.1 is no longer supported,
- .NET Framework 1.1 is still supported

I just assumed that both of those statements couldn't be true at the same time.

Comment: isn't it feasible for you to update (and distribute) your software after 4 or 5 years?

Comment: This is not correct. While it's true you can't install .NET 1.1 on Win64, it comes with .NET 2.0 already installed as part of the OS, and 2.0 will run 1.1 apps just fine. The "support ended" list you provided indicates bug fixes and maintenance support, not application support.

Comment: I want to highlight the question:

Comment: **Is there a note somewhere that if i write a managed application with .NET 2.0 or newer, that it should continue to run on Windows 8, Windows 9, Windows 10...?**

Comment: >>and 2.0 will run 1.1 apps just fine.<< Really? What about the library parts that where specifically broken between 1.x and 2.0?

Comment: People are answering part of your question (whether you can use a .NET 1.1 app on Win 7 x64), but they're missing what I think is the real question. That is, can I rely on .NET apps I write now running far into the future? Stated differently, has Microsoft made the same commitment to backwards compatibility with the .NET Framework as it has/did for Win32? The answer is, best I can tell, no. There's no guarantee that a new version that comes out won't break everything. If you want maximum compatibility (and performance), you still write stuff in Win32.

Comment: @CodyGray - There's no guarantee that what you write in Win32 won't break either.  Microsoft does go through a lot of trouble to ensure compatibility, but that's not a given.  Lots of apps broke when users whent from Win9x to XP.  Lots of apps broke when users went from XP to Vista/7.  There will always be some changes that break certain apps, there is just no way to make major changes without breaking something here and there.  The same is true in .NET.  In fact, i've found .NET to have fewer breaking changes than Win32

Comment: @MystereMan: The apps that broke during those transitions were those that broke the rules in the first place. And the appcompat team worked over time to ensure that even the apps that broke the rules still worked during those transitions. The Win32 team doesn't make breaking changes as a general rule, and when they do, it's not without a *lot* of hand-wringing. The new features are almost always opt-in only, and there are always backwards-compatibility hacks available. You'd have to point to a specific example before I'd believe you.

Comment: @CodyGray - The fact that the 16 bit subsystem was removed in 64 bit windows a prime example of how forward compatibility won't be guaranteed.

Comment: @Mystere: Uh? Yes, when **the underlying architecture** undergoes substantial changes, you might have compatibility problems. That has little to nothing to do with the operating system, of course, and everything to do with the system architecture. Besides, the Windows team supported 16-bit apps for an incredibly long time, and they still do on 32-bit platforms. They've literally bent over backwards to ensure that your 16-bit apps run, if anything that's a perfect example of my argument.

Comment: @MystereMan It should be noted that Microsoft didn't drop support for 16-bit applications: Intel did. When your Pentium processor is in 32-bit mode, it can also run 16-bit machine code. A processor in 64-bit mode can run 32-bit code, but not 16-bit machine code. Windows doesn't run 16-bit applications in 64-bit Windows because your CPU can't run 16-bit applications.

Comment: @IanBoyd - There are techniques to get around that, such as using virtualization.  But MS chose not to do that.  The point being, there are limits to what MS will do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most .NET 1.1 programs should work fine on .NET 2 and even .NET 4 runtimes. The framework has the capability in place of running older versions. The only exceptions are if the application makes use of something that changed between framework versions (so called breaking changes).

Having said that, I don't understand why .NET 2 is not supported as long as .NET 3 and 3.5, since 3 and 3.5 are supersets of .NET 2.

So the answer is, your applications should keep working for a long time to come, unless you happen to have some code that is dependent upon a breaking change.

From the horses mouth, *[Version Compatibility in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx)* (MSDN):

> The .NET Framework 4 is backward-compatible with applications that were built with the .NET Framework versions 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5. In other words, applications and components built with previous versions of the .NET Framework will work on the .NET Framework 4.
>
> However, in practice, this compatibility can be broken by seemingly inconsequential changes in the .NET Framework and changes in programming techniques. For example, performance improvements in the .NET Framework 4 can expose a race condition that did not occur on earlier versions. Similarly, using a hard-coded path to .NET Framework assemblies, performing an equality comparison with a particular version of the .NET Framework, and getting the value of a private field by using reflection are not backward-compatible practices. In addition, each version of the .NET Framework includes bug fixes and security-related changes that can affect the compatibility of some applications and components.

Comment: i guess i'll accept the most upvoted answer as "It should work; i don't know why it's not working for you".  That's an answer i wouldn't want to have to give to a customer in the future.

Answer (score 5):

> If you try to install the .NET Framework version 1.1 on a modern Windows 7 64-bit machine you will get an error - it just won't work. A program written in 2006 is no longer usable; you might as well throw it away.

I don't believe that's true. Unless the application specifically *requires* .NET 1.1 (and not a later version) I would expect it to still work without *any* changes. If that's not quite the case, then an `app.config` file can tell the bootstrapping code to use a newer version of the framework.

In *most* cases I'd expect that to be okay, unless it was relying on something which has been changed in a backwardly-incompatible way. Breaking changes are pretty rare - but they can happen in native code as easily as in managed code.

Comment: It's not so much the application, as the .NET 1.1 Framework installer from Microsoft that fails to install on Windows 7 64-bit. And since the child installer process fails, the software installation fails. It's entirely conceivable if the .NET installer completed, and let the application install, that the application would work.

Comment: @IanBoyd: Right, so the "program written in 2006" is still usable, and there's no need to throw it away - it's only the *installer* which will fail. That's not the same thing at all, IMO.

Comment: Problem is the same: i own a program that i cannot run on current versions of Windows.

Comment: @IanBoyd: It may be the same from a *consumer's* point of view, but your question talks about "a program I write today". Do you need an installer to run your own code? And if you're selling your program and wish to support it, are you unwilling to update your installer to run on later operating systems?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that if you include the libraries you used in your compiled output - as long as Windows exists and works the same way.

Answer (score 1):

"The apps that broke during those transitions were those that broke the rules in the first place." That is wrong.

Why is compatibility difficult to maintain for MS? 
Windows 8 brings a lot of changes compared with Windows 7 for example new codepage (locale) handling in Windows 8.

Example:
Enumerate `InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages` on Windows 8 and get the `CultureInfo` from the languages. If you have the language with locale ID 0x04092000 (spanish, United States) added in Control Panel (keyboard layouts), Framework 2 will throw an exception because it cannot handle this locale. (While the same Framework 2 code works on Windows XP and 7)

```
foreach (InputLanguage lang in InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages)
{
    CultureInfo info = lang.Culture; // throws
}
```

Framework 4 has been updated to handle this. So an old framework may not work on a new OS because of OS changes.

So new .NET frameworks adapt to these OS changes, while old .NET frameworks, that are no longer maintained, will not and the same application does not run anymore on a newer OS.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 3.5 SP1 and components (including 2.0 SP2 and 3.0 SP2) are now supported as a component of Windows and follow it's support lifecycle:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/lifecycle/archive/2010/04/30/net-framework-3-5-sp1-and-later-now-supported-as-part-of-microsoft-windows.aspx