# Dynamic Link Library, Solution can't load assembly

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-core, filenotfoundexception

Recently I started learning how to create Dynamic Link Libraries in Visual Studio with C#.

I followed online instructions on how to create DLLs:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/creating-and-using-dll-class-library-in-C-Sharp/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/04/13/how-to-make-a-simple-dll-as-an-assembly-reference-just-for-fun/

After completing these steps, I tried to add my `.dll` file to my projects.

On execution I receive this message:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 
>   'MySql.Connect, Version=1.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The 
>   system cannot find the file specified.'

I selected .NET Framework 4.6.1 when I started my project. The target framework in the Properties file under the Application tab is selected as .NET Framework 2.0.

The project that should reference to the file is targeting the .Net Core 2 Framework.

I've been at this problem for nearly a week and searched for online solutions.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your second to last paragraph mentions 3 different versions of .net. Either that may cause an issue or it's a typo you should fix

Comment: Also what have you done in your solution. Don't post links to tutorials you followed tells us what YOU did

Comment: Yes @Dave I thought so too, but those are the versions it's set as default. I can't select any other versions for my application (It only allows .Net Core)

Comment: The .DLL application build also don't allow above .NET Framework 2.0

Comment: What I've learned is that you need to show proof that you've tried to do something, there could be fault in the tutorials since VS has updated lately and the process might have changed slightly. So I posted the links to prove I've tried @Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the DLL somewhere that the runtime can find it. The easiest thing to do would be to put it in the same directory as the .exe, but you have other options as well (see [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies)).

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

It is important to carefully decide what platform you intend to use your DLL with.

> I selected.NET Framework 4.6.1 when I started my project.

If you mean when you started your DLL project, then you have limited the types of applications that can consume this DLL to .NET Framework 4.6.1+.

> Properties file under the Application tab is selected as .Net Framework 2.0.

If I understand correctly, you changed the DLL target from .NET Framework 4.6.1 to .NET Framework 2.0. This widens the compatibility so that the consuming library can be .NET Framework 2.0+. However, this is at the expense of all of the newer features of the .NET Framework.

Do note that official support (i.e. patches) for .NET Framework 2.0 has been [gone for several years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539941), and newer machines aren't likely to have it installed.

> The project that should reference to the file is targeting the .Net Core 2 Framework.

Here's the crux of your issue. .NET Core ain't .NET Framework. It is a completely different platform.

That said, .NET Core has some limited support for referencing .NET Framework assemblies, but is it sure not to work with .NET Framework 2.0 (which again, hasn't been supported in years). Also, this "compatibility mode" probably means you lose cross-OS support, which is one of the main benefits of .NET Core.

### Option 1

So, the knee jerk answer is to make your DLL target .NET Core if you want to use it with .NET Core applications.

### Option 2

However, there is also an option to make a **portable** DLL that works with .NET Framework 4.5+ ***and*** .NET Core - make your DLL target [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).

See [How to port from .net framework to .net standard](https://codehollow.com/2017/05/port-net-framework-net-standard/) for instructions on changing your DLL to target .NET Standard.

Comment: Thank you @NightOwl888, the problem was that I moved the files around instead of keeping it stationary. I appreciate your help.